# Azure Container Registry in Azure Web App for Containers across subscriptions

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-registry, azure-web-app-for-containers

I'm currently trying to set up an Azure Web App for Containers, linking it to a Azure Container Registry that lives inside a different subscription. That's why my initial thought was to use the `Private Registry`tab inside the Web apps `Container Settings` to enter the credentials of said Registry.

However when I save and reload the page the settings of the `Azure Container Registry` tab are now populated and the `Private Registry` tab is empty. The issue is, that I get now get following error:

`2020-01-21 21:51:12.951 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"pull access denied for cliswebapi, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"}`

I assume because no password was stored. How do I configure this properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you use the private registry, the Azure Container Registry is also a private registry, and deploy to Web App for Containers, you need to set the environment variables here:

- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME - The username for the ACR server.
- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL - The full URL to the ACR server. (For example, https://my-server.azurecr.io.)
- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD - The password for the ACR server.

See more details in [If you're using Azure Container Registry, you need to set some app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#if-youre-using-azure-container-registry-you-need-to-set-some-app-settingsapplies-to-web-app-for-containers).

And if you create multiple containers, all the images must be in the same registry. All in Docker Hub or Azure Container Registry. See more details in [All images must use the same registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#all-images-must-use-the-same-registryapplies-to-web-app-for-containers).

**Update:**

With the message that you deploy the Web App using the image in the ACR in a different subscription. It seems it's a bug in Web App and you can see the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/743) in the Github. And the suggestion is that maybe you can use the service principal for the ACR to authenticate and the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal#create-a-service-principal).

Comment: It seems these values get auto-populated when I enter them through the Private Registry tab. Still, getting the same error. Do I need to do anything on the Container Registry besides enableing the admin user?

Comment: @Thomas Do you use the service principal to authenticate if you do not enable the admin user? And do you deploy it in the portal?

Comment: @Thomas Id you do not use the service principal, I will say yes, you need to enable the admin user to provide the username and password to the Web App.

Comment: I'm not using a service principal and I have admin enabled, but still seeing this issue.

Comment: @Thomas Do you redeploy your image after enabling the admin user? And do you use a single image or multiple images? And do you check if the value of the environment variables in my answer is the same with your ACR?

Comment: I enabled the admin user when creating the ACR. It's just a single image which I tried to redeploy using a newer build / tag. I also checked that the values in the config are correct.

Comment: @Thomas How do you deploy the image into Web App? In the ACR and deploy it?

Comment: I deploy it from Azure DevOps into ACR and then wanted to manually get it in the Web App from ACR.
Btw. I recreated the ARC instance inside the same subscription and it works immediately. Still, I need to be able to do this across subs.

Comment: @Thomas Not sure, but it seems it's a bug [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/743) in GitHub. Maybe you can use the service principal to authenticate, the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal#create-a-service-principal).

Comment: That's exactly what I'm experiencing. I'll keen an eye out for this to be resolved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Thomas Well, if you do not mind, please accept the answer.

Comment: Please add the links to the bug & workaround to your answer since that's the important part. :)

Comment: @Thomas Update the answer with the link.

Answer (score 2):

I have spend some time on this issue and figured it out. Here is my solution:

Assuming we are having two subscriptions, let's call them `SUB-A` and `SUB-B`, where we are having an Azure Container Registry in `SUB-A` (called `azurebluedev` in my example).

Now we'd like to create an App Service in `SUB-B` that pulls its image of our container registry by using the **admin username**.

It's critical that you use the correct format under `Image and tag` in the docker blade when creating the app service. It must follow the format `url/image:tag` (without https) otherwise you will run into the described problem. I was using `image:tag` format beforehand which didn't work.

[image]

This worked for me!

Comment: This solved my issue, which was just a 404 NotFound error rather than an authentication error.